# XNA creating an in-game file browser for music files

Tags: c#, xna, file-browser

so I'm currently working on a music based game. Much like audio surf, the user selects their audio file and then the game continues to process the level according to the music. Currently I'm using the FileDialog to select file, but this only works in window mode. What would be the easiest way to implement similar functionality with my game even when the game is in full screen. I want to implement something similar to Audio surf, where selecting a folder simply opens the location up.

Edit screenshot and how audio file browser works:
[image]

Before the user can start the game, an audio file must be selected. When the game starts, it simply displays the default directory. The user can traverse directories by clicking on the folder and can go back by clicking the back button. It will display only audio files if they exist in a folder.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how this works in "Audio Surf"

Comment: @Cyral I've made some edits, have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like a ListBox which get refreshed when the user select an item.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/directory-getfiles Seems like you could do something like that.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Do you want us to implement a file browser for you? You just gotta do it :) the File.xxx / Directory.xxx / Path.xxx methods in System.IO should help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement this functionality using [Neoforce](http://neoforce.codeplex.com/) GUI library available for XNA.